# How designing a method doomed to change

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have the following abstract class for some plugin:

```
public abstract class BasePlugin
{
     public void SomeMethod(){..defaultBehaviour}.
}
```

This base class is going to be inherited from several (may be hundreds) of implementations.

I know that for sure, later I am going to change "in a small way" (but still changing) the behaviour of `SomeMethod`.

I would like the existing implementation of `BasePlugin` to continue behaving the same and the new one to use the new Feature.

Is there some pattern that allow me to do that ?

NB : I have the lead on all the implementations but I can not check for the hundreds of implementation if the new behaviour will be fine

Comment: You might look at the decorator pattern or the adapter pattern.

Comment: you could make a new `abstract class BasePlugin2 : BasePlugin`

Comment: What are these plugins going to do? Why would you need so many different plugins?

Comment: I would advise defining an interface, not an abstract base class.

Comment: *Hundreds*??  That makes it the Fingers Crossed Pattern.

Comment: Your question would be greatly improved if you gave more details about the method and how it would change. It's pretty hard to answer this question the way you've posed it.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator : I don't know how the methods change, it is more an empirical statement. Sometimes a new algorithm is introduced, with improvement for most of the case (but with side effect...), sometimes it is a full new behaviour added that requires some new services to be registered, sometimes it is a change on the behaviour itself (for instance a bug fix that change the behaviour or warning that are now handled as errors) etc...

Comment: @HansPassant, I was a bit expensif saying hundreds, it more around 30 but still not really managable to deal with all the plugins. Even if I have access to the plugins' code (readonly), I am not responsible of them and this will take ages to validate with the ends users if the changes are ok for them.

Comment: @Toto, you could define a new common interface ``Plugin`` with ``SomeMethod``. Your abstract class ``BasePlugin`` implements ``Plugin``. If you now have a new feature, define a new abstract class ``BasePluginNew``, for example, that implements ``Plugin``,  New Implementations inherit from ``BasePluginNew``. Old implemetatios continue behaving the same. Client code refers to the common ``Plugin`` interface and is independent of how it is implemented. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Many patterns woud fit, but I'd say [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) is reasonable option assuming you want to keep main part of default behavior intact:

```
public abstract class BasePlugin
{
  public void SomeMethod(){
      // default code before/after one or many variations 
      // to be provided by derived classes
      ...
      Variation(....);
      ...
   }

   public virtual Variation(....) {} // nothing by default
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do that. If you are writing a plugin system you have another option. And that's to expose a number of contracts to the plugins. Each contract represents a type of feature in your application that the plugin can extend.

In your plugin base class you'll define a register method:

```
public abstract class PluginBase
{
    public abstract void Register(IFeatureRepository repos);
}
```

..which the plugins use to register their extensions:

```
public class TextProcessingFilter : PluginBase, ITextProcessor
{
    public void Register(IFeatureRepository repos)
    {
        repos.Get<ITextEditor>().Subscribe(this);
    }

    void ITextProcessor.Process(TextEditorContext ctx)
    {
    }
}
```

The upside with that new features do not break backwards compatibility which is really important if you are going to have a lot of plugins. Simply introduce new interfaces in new versions of the base plugin dll.

Answer (score 0):

`Program to an interface, not an implementation.`

When using a common interface (`Plugin`) for all abstract skeletal implementation classes, you can add a new abstract class (`BasePluginNew`) for implementing new (default) behavior.
New implementations inherit from this new abstract class `BasePluginNew`.
Old implementations continue behaving the same.

Clients refer to the common `Plugin` interface and are independent of how it is implemented.

[image]

For further discussion see the GoF Design Patterns Memory (Design Principles / Interface Design) at http://w3sdesign.com.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the Strategy pattern (due to among other things, ["Prefer composition over inheritance"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) - especially for clients who might already be inheriting from another class):

```
public interface IPluginStrategy
{
    void SomeMethod();
}

public class OldPluginStrategy : IPluginStrategy
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
         // old plugin code
    }
}

public class NewPluginStrategy : IPluginStrategy
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
         // new plugin code which might be using OldPuginStrategy
         // through inheritance or composition
    }
}
```

and for the clients:

```
public class Client
{
    public Client(IPluginStrategy pluginStrategy)
    {
        ...
    }

    // use pluginStrategy's SomeMethod
}
```

Here it is in action:

```
var oldClient = new Client(new OldPluginStrategy());
...
var newClient = new Client(new NewPluginStrategy());
```

you can control which clients use which strategy so old clients can keep using the old plugin code while other (new?) clients will get the new plugin.
You do need access to the clients' code or at least a way to make sure they choose the plugin you want them to use.

A word of caution - if your different plugins are essentially doing the same thing, and you only want to keep different versions in order to avoid the risk of breaking existing clients, please consider the following:

1. This is symptomatic of bad design of your plugin - your clients should not be aware of your plugin internals.
2. This will most likely be extremely hard to maintain in the long run - What happens after 30 changes you've made to the plugin? Will you have 30 different versions of the plugin running in 30 different clients?